# how to make the page not redirect when using webpack's devServer.proxy?

Tags: webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server

here's a project **whose router is in the backend**, image we can open the url `www.example.com/a.htm`. Then I want to use webpack to modularize the js, as you know, all the requests should be redirected to the `www. example.com` instead of `localhost`.

Then I find the `devServer.proxy`:

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    "/": {
      target: "http://www.example.com",
      changeOrigin: true
    }
  }
}
```

but when I open `localhost:8080`, it will be redirected to `www.example.com`, and then it cannot find the bundle.js file.

So here's my question, how to make `localhost:8080` not redirected? or it's wrong to use it this way?

Answer (score 0):

I think this option is reason why it's not worked

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-publicpath-

If I set `publicPath` to something else not `/` (it's by default) proxy server work with root path.

I think becouse this path busy(

**UPDATE:**

But usually need return `index.html` file on `/`...

So, I find solution:

1. Set `publicPath: '/_web_/'` for example
2. After `/?api=for_example` proxy with filter-context `{context: (path, req) => req.query && req.query.api, target: 'http://api.localhost:8080'}`
3. Set proxy from `/` to `/_web_/` with next config `{context: '/', target: 'http://localhost:80', pathRewrite: {'^/' : '/_web_/'}`

Now youre weback-dev-server work: if `api` in query exist - return info from `api.localhost:8080` else return info/file from `/_web_/`.

Good luck